# Get recent nth set of data from tables with Group in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have got a table like this

[image]

Here as you can see there are different groups of data for different dates.
(When we ignore the time part in the datetime there, we have groups of dates)

So what I need is to take most recent from every group and from that result I need to get the recent nth set.

For example if I pass 2, it should return

```
LogId     etime
--------------------
19         2021-07-16
--------------------------
```

Same way if we pass the parameter 3 it should return

```
LogId     etime
--------------------
18         2021-07-15
--------------------------
```

I did some query which I really believe its not the best way and it looks little twisty..

```sql
create table MYTABLE(logid int,etime datetime)
insert into MYTABLE (logid,etime) values
(15,'2021-07-12 01:32:00 PM'),
(16,'2021-07-15 01:32:00 PM'),
(17,'2021-07-15 04:32:00 PM'),
(18,'2021-07-15 07:32:00 PM'),
(19,'2021-07-16 11:32:00 AM'),
(20,'2021-07-16 08:10:00 AM'),
(21,'2021-07-17 11:20:00 PM')
```

```
select logid,etime from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by etime desc) serial from (
select logid,dense_rank() over(partition by cast(etime as date) order by etime desc) drnk,Cast(etime as date) etime from @table
)tbl where drnk=1 )tbl2 where serial=3
```

Could you please share some optimal way

Here is the fiddle
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b387f/1/0)

Comment: Why is the 2nd row `LogId` 19 and not 20? Are you using a zero based index?

Comment: For parameter 2, logid will be 19 because its the latest in that group of 16/07/2021

Comment: What group? There's only 2 columns, there's no group columns... One column has an ID, and another a date and time. Where are the "groups" coming from?

Comment: etime column is the group

Comment: So `19` is returned because it's the only row is its group? So, even though it's the 1st row, and the last row, it can be returned when you ask for the 2nd row? So you're not after the nth value, but the nth value, or the nearest if the nth doesn't exist?

Comment: @Larnu Sorry if you got confused. If I pass parameter 2, it should return second recent item from the table. Since there are 2 in that group, we are taking the latest from it and its logId 19. For LogId 20, the time is 8:32 and for 19 its 11:30

Comment: But there isn't 2 in that group, there's only 1 row. There is only one row with the value `2021-07-16 11:32:00` for `etime`. So why is `logId` `19` returned when it's the first row, not the second>?

Comment: @Larnu (19,'2021-07-16 11:32:00 AM'),
(20,'2021-07-16 08:10:00 AM'),

Comment: `2021-07-16 11:32:00 AM` <> `2021-07-16 08:10:00 AM`... They are different values because they are different times... Again, where is the group coming from as it's not `etime` on it own.

Comment: @Larnu But please check the date friend, ignore the time, thats why I am casting it in dense_rank and order it using time

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the OP wants: 1) The recent row for each date as _result1_, and 2) The `Nth` row from _result1_ as final result.

Comment: So the grouping is on the date portion of `etime` *not* `etime`..? Why didn't you say that...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `OFFSET` and `FETCH` would be more succinct here:

```sql
DECLARE @N int = 2,
        @Date date = '20210716';

SELECT LogID, etime
FROM dbo.MYTABLE
WHERE etime >= @Date
  AND eTime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date)
ORDER BY etime ASC
OFFSET @N-1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: But we are passing @N parameter only for nth recent row get returned. May be I misunderstood your answer, which is having a @Date parameter I can see.

Comment: Then where do the groupings come in? You haven't explained the problem here, @SandeepThomas . YOu talk about groupings, but then state you aren't providing a value for that group, so how do you know what group you're looking at?

Comment: @Larnu Sorry for that... I updated the question specifying grouping using date ignoring the time part.

Answer (score 1):

Imo the way you're doing it now is a really good way and you could stick with it.  Again imo: the nested SELECT are not as nice as common table expressions.  I would rewrite and parameterize the code something like this

```
declare @param              int=3;

with
dr_cte(logid, etime_dt, drnk) as (
    select logid, Cast(etime as date),
           dense_rank() over(partition by cast(etime as date) order by etime desc)           
    from #MYTABLE),
serial_cte(logid, etime_dt, drnk, serial) as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by etime_dt desc)
    from dr_cte
    where drnk=1)
select *
from serial_cte
where serial=@param;
```

[EDIT] It could be made a tiny bit more concise (or maybe it's the same?) by using TOP 1 WITH TIES in the dr_cte.  Then the WHERE condition in the second CTE could be removed.  Afaik this code is equivalent

```
declare @param              int=2;

with
dr_cte(logid, etime_dt) as (
    select top 1 with ties logid, Cast(etime as date)
    from #MYTABLE
    order by row_number() over(partition by cast(etime as date) order by etime desc)),
serial_cte(logid, etime_dt, serial) as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by etime_dt desc)
    from dr_cte)
select *
from serial_cte
where serial=@param;
```

[Edit 2] It could also be done by OFFSET paging.

```
declare @param              int=3;

with
dr_cte(logid, etime_dt) as (
    select top 1 with ties logid, Cast(etime as date)
    from #MYTABLE
    order by row_number() over(partition by cast(etime as date) order by etime desc))
select *
from dr_cte
order by etime_dt desc
offset @param-1 rows fetch next 1 rows only;
```